# Warning[212] Enhanced 16cxxx devices should specify __CONFIG address

Tags: assembly, pic

Using the GPUTILS to compile assembler for Microchip PICs, I got this following warning:

> Warning[212] Enhanced 16cxxx devices should specify __CONFIG address.

It seem related to the address required for the configuration words, which in my case (`PIC16F1703`), it is 8007h and 8008h.

How could I solve this warning?

Note: the code was done for PIC16F628A.

```
; Simple program to make a led (connected to RC3, pin 7)

        processor   16F1703
        radix       dec
        include     p16f1703.inc
        errorlevel  -302
        __config    _CP_OFF & _LVP_OFF & _BOREN_OFF & _MCLRE_ON & _PWRTE_ON & _WDTE_OFF

; constants
led     equ 3

; User ID Locations
;       org H'8000'
;       dw  H'0'
;       dw  H'1'
;       dw  H'2'
;       dw  H'3'

; EEPROM data
;       org H'2100'
;       de  "Led example"

; variables in ram
        org H'20'
i       res 1
j       res 1

; reset vector
        org H'00'
        goto    setup

; interrupt vector
        org H'04'


setup   clrf    PORTA
;       movlw   H'07'       ;Turn comparators off and enable
;       movwf   CMCON       ;pins for I/O functions
;       bsf STATUS, RP0
        movlw   B'00110111'
        movwf   TRISC
        movlw   B'00111111'
        movwf   TRISA
;       bcf STATUS, RP0

start   bcf PORTC, led
        call    delay
        bsf PORTC, led
        call    delay
        goto    start


delay   movlw   255
        movwf   j
        movwf   i
        decfsz  i, F
        goto    $-1
        decfsz  j, F
        goto    $-4
        return

        end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [gputils](http://gputils.sourceforge.net/gputils.pdf) help file:

> gplink requires a linker script. This script tells gplink what memory
>   is available in the target processor. A set of Microchip generated
>   scripts are installed with gputils. These scripts were intended as a
>   starting point, but for many applications they will work as is. If the
>   user does not specify a linker script, gplink will attempt to use the
>   default script for the processor reported in the object file. The
>   default location of the scripts is reported in the gplink help message

So, in this file must be declared start and end config address something like:

```
__CONFIG_START 0x8007
__CONFIG_END 0x800A
```

You can declare addresses also at the begining of your program!

Comment: I found a 16f1703_g.lkr file in the gputils folder. It contains already a line like : "CODEPAGE NAME=.config START=0x8007 END=0x8008 PROTECTED". I tried to add "__CONFIG_START equ 0x8007", but no improvement.

Comment: @Adrian Maire: Try manualy to specify a linker script file in to the project and check the gputils help because you can read that __CONFIG is deprecated use CONFIG directive instead.